# How in tox run bash script and reuse returned value?

Tags: python, bash, tox

When I create a tox environment, some libraries are installed under different paths depending on the environment that I use to trigger tox:

```
# Tox triggered inside virtual env
.tox/lib/site-packages
```

Sometimes

```
# Tox triggered inside docker
.tox/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

I need to reuse such path in further steps inside tox env. I decided to create a bash script to find the path for installed libraries to be able to reuse it and to run it inside tox env. I thought that I can pass found path to tox and reuse it in one of the next commands. Is it possible to do such thing?

I tried:

**tox.ini**

```
[tox]
envlist =
    docs
min_version = 4
skipsdist = True
allowlist_externals = cd
passenv =
    HOMEPATH
    PROGRAMDATA
basepython = python3.8

[testenv:docs]
changedir = docs
deps =
    -r some_path/library_name/requirements.txt
commands =
    my_variable=$(bash ../docs/source/script.sh)
    sphinx-apidoc -f -o $my_variable/source $my_variable
```

But apparently this doesn't work with tox:

> docs: commands[0] docs> my_variable=$(bash ../docs/source/script.sh)
> docs: exit 2 (0.03 seconds)  docs>
> my_variable=$(bash../docs/source/script.sh) docs: FAIL code 2
> (0.20=setup[0.17]+cmd[0.03] seconds)   evaluation failed :( (0.50
> seconds)

Bash script

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

tox_env_path="../.tox/docs/"
conf_source="source"

tox_libs=$(find . $tox_env_path -type d -name "<name of library>")

sudo mkdir -p $tox_libs/docs/source
cp $conf_source/conf.py $conf_source/index.rst $tox_libs/docs/source

echo $tox_libs
```

Comment: Does the following work? `sphinx-apidoc -f -o {env_site_packages_dir}/source {env_site_packages_dir}`

Comment: No, it crashes even earlier - at this stage: 'my_variable=$(bash' '../docs/source/script.sh)'

Comment: In my suggestion you do not need the `my_variable`, you would need to delete that line entirely.

Comment: Ok, but then how I can find the path (which happens inside bash script) and reuse it in the next command with sphinx?

Comment: In `tox.ini` you can use the [substitution](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#substitutions) [_`{env_site_packages_dir}`_](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#env_site_packages_dir). Maybe this is helpful for you, instead of trying to compute it in the bash script. Just try it... As a test you can try `commands = python -c 'print("path is: {env_site_packages_dir}")'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but maybe something like this can help you achieve the actual goal ([XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)):

```ini
[testenv:docs]
# ...
allowlist_externals =
    bash
commands =
    python -c 'print("The path is: {env_site_packages_dir}")'
    bash ../docs/source/script.sh
    sphinx-apidoc -f -o {env_site_packages_dir}/LibName/source {env_site_packages_dir}/LibName
```

Indeed, it seems to me like it is unnecessary to compute the path in the bash script and try to read this path in a variable.

***1.*** As far as I know it is not possible to assign values to a variable like you suggest in your question, `tox.ini` does not allow it.

***2.*** On the other hand, `tox.ini` allows [subsitutions](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#substitutions) and in particular the [*`{env_site_packages_dir}`*](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#env_site_packages_dir) seems helpful for your use case.

Comment: Great! That's perfect. Thanks! I must have missed it reading the documentation. However, by your suggestion, I found out that the main issue is not the way of getting the path itself. But the fact that in the virtual environment Tox is using bash from WSL. Thus, even your solution doesn't work at the end, because tox will create the path in Unix style due to WSL, and in docker it will use Windows coding style and they will affect what will be behind {env_site_packages_dir}. Not know completely why it's like that, but I found that it's like that, and it's not the main point of a question :)

Comment: Yeah, I do not know what this path difference between environments is about. If you post it as its own independent question, maybe you will get an answer with the real reason. -- But honestly I do not know why in WSL it can possibly be different than in a Docker container. Typically they are both Linux.